# Tuple relational calculus: existential quantifiers

Tags: sets, first-order-logic, relational-calculus, tuple-relational-calculus

I have the following question and given answer:

> Question: List the names of managers who have at least one dependant.
>
> Answer: `{e.Fname, e.Lname | EMPLOYEE(e) AND (∃d)(∃t)(DEPARTMENT(d) AND DEPENDANT(t) AND e.Ssn = d.Mgrssn AND t.Essn = e.Ssn) }`

My answer was exactly the same except that instead of the `(∃d)(∃t)(...)` section I said `(∃d)(DEPARTMENT(d) AND e.Ssn = d.Mgrssn) AND (∃t)(DEPENDANT(t) AND t.Essn = e.Ssn)`.

Are these equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me concentrate, as you asked, on section $(\exists d)(\exists t)(\cdots)$.

In case when one part of conjuction is "not depend" on letter under existence quantifier, holds
$$(\exists d)(A \text{ and } B)\Leftrightarrow  (\exists d)(A) \text{ and } B$$
Where we assume $B$ does not containt letter $d$.
$$$$
In your case, for simplicity, let make following designations:
$$\begin{array}{l}
A(d) = \text{ DEPARTMENT(d) }\\
B(t) = \text{ DEPENDANT(t) } \\
C(d) = (\text{e.Ssn = d.Mgrssn})\\
E(t) = (\text{t.Essn = e.Ssn})
\end{array}$$
and assume, that $A,C$ doesn't depend on $t$ and $B,E$ doesn't depend on $d$. Then we have

$$(\exists d)(\exists t)\big(A(d) \text{ and } B(t)\text{ and } C(d) \text{ and } E(t)\big) \Leftrightarrow \\
\Leftrightarrow (\exists d)\big(A(d) \text{ and } C(d)\big) \text{ and } (\exists t) \big(B(t)\text{ and } E(t)\big)$$
So, you are right, they are equivalent in reviewed case.

Generally we cannot distribute existence quantifier  with respect to $\text{AND}$(conjunction) operation as shows example: take $A=$"$d$ is even" and $B=$"$d$ is odd". Then, of course, sentence "$(\exists d)(A) \text{ and } (\exists d)(B)$" is true, but sentence "$(\exists d)(A \text{ and } B)$" is false.